# Is `reinterpret_cast<char*>(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&ch) + 1) == &ch +1` guaranteed?

Tags: c++, alignment

I'm writing alignment-dependent code, and quite surprised that there's no standard function testing if a given pointer is aligned properly.

It seems that most code on the internet use `(long)ptr` or `reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(ptr)` to test the alignment and I also used them, but I wonder if using the casted pointer to integral type is standard-conformant.

Is there any system that fires the assertion here?

```
char ch[2];
assert(reinterpret_cast<char*>(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&ch[0]) + 1)
       == &ch[1]);
```

Comment: How does that expression check for alignment?

Comment: There might be some systems where the code doesn't compile, as `uintptr_t` is optionally defined.  An *"unsigned integer type capable of holding a pointer"* isn't required to exist.

Comment: @MikeMB That expression is not used for alignment check, but the alignment is checked with LSB of reinterpret'ed pointer, so I think that expresion is a necessary condition for the alignment check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the question in the title: No.

Counter example:  On the old Pr1me mini-computer, a normal pointer was two 16-bit words.  First word was 12-bit segment number, 2 ring bits, and a flag bit (can't remember the 16th bit).  Second word was a 16-bit word offset within a segment.  A char* (and hence void*) needed a third word.  If the flag bit was set, the third word was either 0 or 8 (being the bit offset within the addressed word).  A `uintptr_t` for such a machine would need to be `uint48_t` or `uint64_t`.  Either way, adding 1 to such an integer would not advance to the next character in memory.

A capability addressed machine is also likely to have pointers which are much larger than the address space, and there is no particular reason why the least significant part of the corresponding integer should be part of the "address" rather than part of the extra info.

In practise of course, nobody is writing C++ for a Pr1me, and capability addressed machines seem not to have appeared either.  It will work on all real systems - but the standard doesn't guarantee it.

Comment: More realistically/recent, the classic 8086 20 bits addresses in 16:16 format might fail when `ch[2]` straddles a segment boundary. `0000:FFFF +1` is `1000:0000` not `0001:0000`.

Comment: Ooh!  Excellent example.